# How to find what random row from a random table was chosen

Tags: php, mysql, sql, random

I'm trying to create a website where users can vote on different items from a game, like a tierlist. I want the item that a user votes on to be from a random table and a random row in that table.

Right now, I have the following code set up to find the random item:

```
$ran = mt_rand(1, 10);
switch ($ran) {
    case "1":$sql = "SELECT item, rating FROM ditems ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";  
         $result = $conn->query($sql);  
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row["gun"];
         };
         break;
    case "2":$sql = "SELECT item, rating FROM citems ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";  
         $result = $conn->query($sql);  
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row["item"];
         }; 
etc
```

The problem I run into is that I can't access what the chosen item is outside of the `switch{}` statement because the `$row` array is declared locally, but I have to be able to do that so that I can seet up a button to vote on the item.

EDIT: I decided to throw all items in a single table and pick a item using 
    ORDER BY RAND LIMIT 1

Comment: Do your items have any ids that you could use to pair the items? Can you show a bit more of your code? Right now I do not see enough information to be able to help you.

Comment: Why have more than one table?

Comment: Why do you use `while` when your queries return just one record? and then you have `$ran` which specifies which table you have fetched the record, why can't you just use that to setup the button? and also same here as @Strawberry, why do you have more than one table?! does the data structure of these tables vary from each other?

Answer (score 0):

You can `SELECT` another column with a text constant to denote what entity is selected:

```
$ran = mt_rand(1, 10);
switch ($ran) {
    case "1":$sql = "SELECT 'ditem' as entity, item, rating FROM ditems ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";  
         $result = $conn->query($sql);  
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row["gun"];
         };
         break;
    case "2":$sql = "SELECT 'citem' as entity, item, rating FROM citems ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";  
         $result = $conn->query($sql);  
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row["item"];
         }; 
etc
```